# Adobe Analytics DTM custom script prop not setting

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I am trying to show the last time I made a published change and the current library version

I created a data element Global - Example: 
return "DTM:" + _satellite.publishDate.split(" ")[0] + "|" + "Adobe:" + s.version;

Then I set a prop to my %Global - Example%.

It doesn't work. So I tried to debug in the console. When console.log("DTM:" + _satellite.publishDate.split(" ")[0] + "|" + "Adobe:" + s.version); it works in the console and  I get the the last publish date and the current version of the library. However, it won't work for some reason in dtm.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to show the last time I made a published change and the current library version.

Comment: without more info (e.g. where/when you are attempting to use this vs. other things) my first guess is `s` object doesn't yet exist when you attempt to reference it. My 2nd guess is.. sometimes DTM is weird about data element names because it attempts to allow you to do js vars and even methods, things like `%this.getAttribute(foo)%`. Try renaming it to something like "global_example" (underscore instead spaces and hyphen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Data Element in this case will have an impact on timing.

If you add your code to the Adobe Analytics Custom Code section of a rule or AA Global Code you should be able to set your prop just fine.

```
s.prop1 = _satellite.publishDate.split(" ")[0] + "|" + "Adobe:" + s.version);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it works in the custom code but not anywhere else, and I guess I was wondering if there was another way but im seeing that there is not

Comment: if you deploy this via custom code in a global page load rule or in the custom code of the AA tool it should work everywhere.